# Angular momentum of a cylindrical system in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, angular-momentum, hamiltonian-formalism

The definition of energy and enegry flux of a cylindrical symmetric system in general relativity is given by Kip Throne in [Phys. Rev. 138, B251](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.138.B251) and generalized by Chandrasekhar in [Proc. Roy. Soc. Lond. A 408, 209 (1986)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2398161?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) for non-diagonal case so called C-energy and C-enegry flux.

My question is whether this derivation of enegry could be generalized to define the (conserved) angular monmentum of a infinitely Long, cylindrically symmetric systems in general relativity ?

Comment: Have a look at this paper: by H. Bondi, “The angular momentum of cylindrical systems in general relativity”, https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1994.0091

Comment: @A.V.S. Thank you！But I have a little question to it. In this paper Bondi start his calculation with Weyl-Papapetrou form of the metric. However, this form Bondi use in the paper is slightly different form other reference. So what is the coordinate transformation to make them coincident？